# Choosing dates that are selectable in js for a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a datepicker that makes dates previous from current date unselectable. I am new to js and would like a to know how to do it. I did not know what to google exactly and didn't find the right answer. Pls help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several JS datepicker solutions out there and most of them have pretty straightforward solutions to do what you want. E.g. [JQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

[Here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) you can see an example of doing this with JQuery UI Datepicker.